column recognition issues with load_dataset() when training controlnet
i'm unable to load my dataset for controlnet training using load_dataset(). however, load_from_disk() seems to work? would appreciate if someone can explain why that's the case here

Error

11/25/2024 17:12:18 - INFO - __main__ - Initializing controlnet weights from unet
Generating train split: 1 examples [00:00, 334.85 examples/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/data/user/user/signwriting_illustration/controlnet_huggingface/diffusers/examples/controlnet/train_controlnet.py", line 1189, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "/data/user/user/signwriting_illustration/controlnet_huggingface/diffusers/examples/controlnet/train_controlnet.py", line 923, in main
    train_dataset = make_train_dataset(args, tokenizer, accelerator)
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/data/user/user/signwriting_illustration/controlnet_huggingface/diffusers/examples/controlnet/train_controlnet.py", line 639, in make_train_dataset
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: `--image_column` value 'image' not found in dataset columns. Dataset columns are: _data_files, _fingerprint, _format_columns, _format_kwargs, _format_type, _output_all_columns, _split


for reference here's the structure of the original training files before dataset creation

- dir train
     - dir A (illustrations)
     - dir B (SignWriting)
     - prompt.json containing:
       {"source": "B/file.png", "target": "A/file.png", "prompt": "..."}


here are features after dataset creation

  "features": {
    "control_image": {
      "_type": "Image"
    },
    "image": {
      "_type": "Image"
    },
    "caption": {
      "dtype": "string",
      "_type": "Value"
    }


I've also attempted to upload the dataset to huggingface with the same error output

Environment


accelerate 1.1.1
huggingface-hub 0.26.2
python 3.11
torch 2.5.1
transformers 4.46.2
STEPS TO RECREATE ERROR:

dataset creation script

controlnet training script used

training parameters -


! accelerate launch diffusers/examples/controlnet/train_controlnet.py \
 --pretrained_model_name_or_path="stable-diffusion-v1-5/stable-diffusion-v1-5" \
 --output_dir="$OUTPUT_DIR" \
 --train_data_dir="$HF_DATASET_DIR" \
 --conditioning_image_column=control_image \
 --image_column=image \
 --caption_column=caption \
 --resolution=512\
 --learning_rate=1e-5 \
 --validation_image "./validation/0a4b3c71265bb3a726457837428dda78.png" "./validation/0a5922fe2c638e6776bd62f623145004.png" "./validation/1c9f1a53106f64c682cf5d009ee7156f.png" \
 --validation_prompt "An illustration of a man with short hair" "An illustration of a woman with short hair" "An illustration of Barack Obama" \
 --train_batch_size=4 \
 --num_train_epochs=500 \
 --tracker_project_name="sd-controlnet-signwriting-test" \
 --hub_model_id="sarahahtee/signwriting-illustration-test" \
 --checkpointing_steps=5000 \
 --validation_steps=1000 \
 --report_to wandb \
 --push_to_hub


command -
sbatch --export=HUGGINGFACE_TOKEN=hf_token,WANDB_API_KEY=api_key script.sh

